# Entity model wizard lack of table documentation

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odac

I am using ODAC 11.2 r4 to create an entity model in visual studio 2010. Right now I am testing out what all the wizard will auto generate off my oracle database and I would like to figure out how to generate documentation based off the database. I have set comments to both my table and columns, but that isn't shown on the entity side. Is there a way I could have my documentation automatically generated off these comments or some other string I set on the database side?

Comment: No unless you write your own tool to generate EDMX for you.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka this saddens me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, EF does not support this out of the box. Not even for SQL Server. However, there are some 3rd party tools out there which support this. For SQL server: [Entity Framework SQL Server Document Generator](http://eftsqldocgenerator.codeplex.com/) (free). And for Oracle [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) (Commercial). (v. 6.70 supports transferring comments to the Summary attribute.)